# Scratch 3.0 taking in a byte array for loading

Tags: mit-scratch

I have been working on a project that is implementing Scratch 3.0 for a learning tool for children. We are going to be hosting it on an azure web application. We have hit a bit of a wall though and we aren't really sure how to get past it. The issue that we are having is that we are trying to have a user click on a project that they want to load into the Scratch 3.0 GUI and have a new page open where the user can then play/edit the project. However, Scratch 3.0 does not seem to have a functionality to do that yet. They have a loading feature that allows a file to be directly uploaded from the users computer though.

Is there anyway to change the function so that it would read a project from a byte array that would be sent from another web page?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Since this seems to be pretty Scratch-specific, you might get better results asking on the Scratch forums: https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/31/